# Professeur/maitresse

Tags: genre, terminologie

Quelques questions à propos du système scolaire en France:

**Quand est-ce qu'on utilise le titre *"prof/professeur"* plutôt que *"maîtresse"*?** S'agit il du fait qu'un *prof* enseigne  une matière spécifique (comme  "un prof de maths") ou simplement de l'âge des étudiants?

**Est-ce que l'utilisation des termes genrés, tels comme "professeur/professeure" et "maître/maîtresse", correcte ?** (Correct selon les usages, comme, par exemple, l'avocat est toujours "maître", même s'il s'agit d'une femme.)

**Remarque:**
[Une question un peu similaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/41608/9870)

Comment: grammaticalement correcte?? Ou acceptable selon les usages?

Comment: @Lambie acceptable selon les usage. Merci pour cette correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les élèves qui s'adressent à un enseignant en France l'appellent *maître* ou *maîtresse* quand ils sont dans le primaire et *monsieur* ou *madame* dans le secondaire. Monsieur et madame peuvent être suivis par le nom de l'enseignant, mais ce n'est jamais le cas avec *maître/maîtresse* ou *professeur/professeure*. *Maître + patronyme* ne se dit que pour un notaire ou un avocat, ou parfois humoristiquement ([Maître Capelo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Capelovici)).

Quand on s'adresse par courrier à un enseignant, on n'utilise donc pas de titre autre que *Monsieur* ou *Madame*. Ce pourra être au choix *Mme Martin, professeur de mathématiques* ou *Mme Martin, professeure de mathématiques*, *M. Bernard, professeur des écoles* etc.

On trouvera encore souvent des *M. Bernard, instituteur* même si ce nom n'est plus officiel.